# How can I scrape the ID tags and their Content(text) from a website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nlp

At the top of [this site](https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-lamivudine-and-zidovudine-tablets.html) are 17 ID tags:

```
1.Boxed warning
2.Indications
3.Dosage/Administration
4.Dosage forms
5.Contraindications
6.Warnings/Precautions
7.Adverse reactions
8.Drug interactions
9.Specific populations
10.Overdosage
11.Description
12.Clinical pharmacology
13.Nonclinical toxicology
14.Clinical studies
15.How supplied
16.Patient counseling
17.Medication guide
```

I want to scrape the page and make a dictionary with those tags as the keys. How can I do this? Here's what I've tried so far:

```
urls = "https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-lamivudine-and-zidovudine-tablets.html"
response = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
data3 = soup.findAll('h2')
out = {}
y1 = []
y2 = []
for header in data3:
   x0 = header.get('id')
   y1.append(x0)
   nextNode = header
   while True:
      nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
      if nextNode is None:
          break
      if isinstance(nextNode, NavigableString):
          x1 = nextNode.strip()
      if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
          if nextNode.name == "h2":
              break

      x2 = nextNode.get_text(strip=True).strip()
      x3 = x1 + " " + x2
      y2.append(x3)
 print(y1,y2)
```

I'm getting

```
Output I'm Getting: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None] [content]

Desired Output: ['boxed warning', 'indications', 'dosage/administration', 'dosage forms', 'contraindications', 'warnings/precautions', 'adverse reactions', 'drug interactions', 'specific populations', 'overdosage', 'description', 'clinical pharmacology', 'nonclinical toxicology', 'clinical studies', 'how supplied', 'patient counseling', 'medication guide'] ['content present under boxed warning', 'content present under indications']
```

How can I get a dictionary or list that replaces all the Nones with the list of tags? I'm struggling to work with the structure of the webpage. Thank you!

Comment: What's the code you've already tried?

Comment: @BLimitless i've edited the question and added the code i've tried. looking forward from hearing you

Comment: Great, thank you. Seeing your code I unfortunately don't know how to help you. But I now see how to modify the question so you should get some answers. Hopefully my edit to the question will go through soon, and then someone with better knowledge of web scraping should be able to help you out. Good luck!

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? For example, if `Boxed warning` is the key, what's the value? Or, instead of a dictionary, is it just a list of all the tags on the page?

Comment: I want all the Ids of the Tags under the Drugs name such as "Boxed Warnings", "Indications", "Dosage Administration", "Dosage Form" and others along with the content for all those Headers I need text that is present in the page.

For example:
['Boxed Warning', 'Indications', rest all other tags ] [the text of the page related to that particular id]

@JackFleeting

Comment: I'm sorry, but you'll have to find another way to explain what you want because I don't get it. When you do, edit the question (don't post another comment) and show **exactly** (don't just describe) the expected output (or a representative sample of the output, if it's too long).

Comment: OK, I think I can get you at least most of the way there, but since this is a fairly complex document, it's easier, in my opinion, to do it using xpath instead of css selectors and other beautifulsoup methods. However, since beautifulsoup doesn't support xpath, it will have to be done using lxml, if available to you.

Comment: I have been learning beautifulsoup recently and trying out various things. I would surely explore on LXML like you mentioned. Looking forward for the solution, I've been struggling from over a week to find an appropriate solution. And also I'm new to Stack over flow. So, if I was wrong, pardon me @Jack Fleeting

Comment: @flameline Hey, you got some answers! Glad this is working out. Keep editing the question to make it clearer if the answers aren't getting you what you want. This was a complicated first question for StackOverflow, so keep with it. It'll get easier/faster to get help here. Good luck! And don't forget to upvote/accept an answer that works for you so the community knows when to move on (and other people with similar questions in the future know they can look here for an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you need, but based on the comments I think this is what you are looking for.  You can easily add the output to a list or a dictionary.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urls = "https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-lamivudine-and-zidovudine-tablets.html"
response = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find('div', {'class': 'ddc-anchor-links'})

available_information = []

for tag in tags.find_all('a'):
    available_information.append(tag.text)
    

print(available_information)
# output
['Boxed Warning', 'Indications and Usage', 'Dosage and Administration', 'Dosage Forms and Strengths', 'Contraindications', 'Warnings and Precautions', 'Adverse Reactions/Side Effects', 'Drug Interactions', 'Use In Specific Populations', 'Overdosage', 'Description', 'Clinical Pharmacology', 'Nonclinical Toxicology', 'Clinical Studies', 'How Supplied/Storage and Handling', 'Patient Counseling Information', 'Medication Guide']
```

You can obtain the content for each TOC using this code:

```
anchor_tags = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find('div', {'class': 'ddc-toc-content'})
for tag in tags.find_all('a'):
    anchor_tag = str(tag['href']).replace('#', '')
    anchor_tags.append(anchor_tag)

for tag in anchor_tags:
    anchor_tag = soup.find("a", {"id": tag})
    header_tag = anchor_tag.find_next_sibling('h2')
    # now you need to figure out how you want to store this information that is being extracted.
```

Based on our chat conversation you can query multiple pages that have different structures this way.  You will have to modified the search_terms and known_tags as you scrape more pages with different structures.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_soup(target_url):
    response = requests.get(target_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def obtain_toc_content(soup):
    available_information = []
    anchor_tags = []
    known_tags = ['div', 'ul']
    search_terms = ['ddc-toc-content', 'ddc-anchor-links']
    for tag, search_string in zip(known_tags, search_terms):
        tag_found = bool(soup.find(tag, {'class': search_string}))
        if tag_found:
            toc = soup.find(tag, {'class': search_string})
            for toc_tag in toc.find_all('a'):
                available_information.append(toc_tag.text)
                anchor_tag = str(toc_tag['href'])
                anchor_tags.append(anchor_tag)

    return available_information, anchor_tags


urls = ['https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-lamivudine-and-zidovudine-tablets.html',
        'https://www.drugs.com/ajovy.html','https://www.drugs.com/cons/a-b-otic.html']
for url in urls:
    make_soup = get_soup(url)
    results = obtain_toc_content(make_soup)
    table_of_content = results[0]
    toc_tags = results[1]
```

Comment: Desired Output: ['boxed warning', 'indications', 'dosage/administration', 'dosage forms', 'contraindications', 'warnings/precautions', 'adverse reactions', 'drug interactions', 'specific populations', 'overdosage', 'description', 'clinical pharmacology', 'nonclinical toxicology', 'clinical studies', 'how supplied', 'patient counseling', 'medication guide'] ['content present under boxed warning', 'content present under indications']

Comment: I added the items to a list.  I don't see 'content present under indications' or 'content present under indications' on the page?

Comment: In the URL if you click on "Description" you'll be dragged to heading "Abacavir, Lamivudine and Zidovudine Tablets Description" in the page. I want content under that heading till the next heading "Abacavir, Lamivudine and Zidovudine Tablets - Clinical Pharmacology" as well

Comment: So you only want the text under "Description" or you do want all the text for all TOC elements?

Comment: I need text for all TOC elements

Comment: where is the extracted information stored in? I could see anchor_tags only

Comment: @Flameling my note in the code, stated that you need to determine how you wanted to store the info.  I wouldn't store this data in a list, but maybe in a dictionary or even JSON.  Doing this requires more effort and testing.   Are you planning to scrape information for other drugs?

Comment: it would be amazing to store data in the form of dictionary. I'm writing logic so it can be used to download for all drugs of letter 'A' as my next goal.
so, for each Drug I can make a dictionary with Tags and content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233616/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-flameling).

Answer (score 1):

The code below should get you at least close to where I believe you want to go. I'll try to explain as much as I can on the way, but there's a lot for you to learn:

```
import lxml.html as lh
url = 'https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-lamivudine-and-zidovudine-tablets.html#s-42231-1'
req = requests.get(url)

doc = lh.fromstring(req.text)

headers = doc.xpath('//ul[@class="ddc-anchor-links"]//li')
head_names = [] #when the code is done running, this list will contain the headers
anchors = [] #this list will contain the reference to the text elements for each header
for header in headers:
    head_names.append(header.xpath('a/text()')[0])
    anchors.append(header.xpath('a/@href')[0].replace('#',''))
for anchor in anchors:
    #now to iterate through each reference to get to the actual text:
    target = doc.xpath(f'//a[@id="{anchor}"]')[0] #this uses f-strings; you may need to read up on that
    ind = anchors.index(anchor)+1 #because of the structure of the page, this next block will help us determine when the text for one header ends, and the next one begins; you'll have to play with it to see how it actually works:
    for z in target.xpath('./following-sibling::*'):
        try:
            if (z.xpath('name()'))=="a"  and z.xpath('./@id')[0]==anchors[ind]:
                break
        except:
            continue #this is necessary because the last header doesn't have a "next" header
        else:
            print(z.xpath('.//text()'))
```

The text output will not be pretty, but will contain the desired information. You will have to play with stripping, formatting, etc. to get it to look like you want it to.

Comment: I've made a change - headers = doc.xpath('//div[@class="ddc-toc-content"]') but it shows list index out-of-range in head_names.append(header.xpath('a/text()')[0]). I've edited the class name as the one you suggested has not worked

Comment: @Flameling Not sure what the problem is; it works for me.

Comment: I copy pasted the same code which you've given and it doesn't show me any output. I don't understand why. Can you explain me what first for loop does?

Comment: @Flameling I see what happened - the site actually changed the html structure from yesterday; the headers are now under `//div[@class="ddc-toc-content"]//ul//li/a/text()`, etc. Maybe they've experienced too much scraping activity...

Comment: Now the code worked but alot of work needed to make the data pretty and eliminate the unnecessary things

Comment: @JackFleeting I noted that the page structure changed multiple times when I was testing my answer.  I also noted that each drug page is different, so the code has to be modified if additional pages need to be scraped.

Comment: @Flameling Unfortunately, that happens a lot with webscraping, pages are changed frequently to deter it. Although in this case, not sure exactly why they would object.

Comment: @Flameling I didn't notice - I just downloaded it once (using requests) and from there worked offline. Not smart....

Comment: Actually, I want to automate a code where I could get list of tags and content between each tag to create a data frame out of it. Gotta work on it now but pretty much less idea of lmxl to make the data pretty.